# Converting 3.3V input to degrees Fahrenheit

Tags: temperature, analog-to-digital

I have a temp sensor (TMP 36) the same one used in the guide I am following  [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/tmp36-temperature-sensor/using-a-temp-sensor). I have impossible temp output. Anyone know what I did wrong?

```
216 temp (def F): 116582.0
216 temp (def F): 116582.0
216 temp (def F): 116582.0
215 temp (def F): 116042.0
216 temp (def F): 116582.0
```

Here is the python script I am running:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
#board pins
#pin 3=SDA
#pin 5=SCL

from smbus import SMBus

bus = SMBus(1)

bus.write_byte(0x48, 0) # i2cget -y 1
last_reading =-1

while(0 == 0): # do forever
    reading = bus.read_byte(0x48) # read A/D
    #Voltage at pin in milliVolts = (reading from ADC) * (3300/1024) #on 3.3v input
    milivolts=reading*(3300/1024)
    degC=(milivolts - 0.5) * 100 
    degF = (degC * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0;
    print(str(reading)+' temp (def F): '+str(degF))
    time.sleep(3)#sec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Adafruit tutorial you refer to:

> **Voltage at pin in milliVolts = (reading from ADC) * (3300/1024)**
> This formula converts the number 0-1023 from the ADC into 0-3300mV (=
> 3.3V)
>
> Then, to convert millivolts into temperature, use this formula:
>
> **Centigrade temperature = [(analog voltage in mV) - 500] / 10**

You seem to be doing the first conversion right, but the second conversion wrong. You are doing

> **Centigrade temperature = [(analog voltage in mV) - 0.5] * 100**

The following Python3 output shows how your method gives the wrong result, while using the correct formula for `degC` gives the correct temperature reading:

> >>> r = 216
>
> >>> mV = r * (3300/1024)
>
> >>> print(mV)
>
> 696.09375
>
> >>> degC_wrong = (mV-0.5)*100
>
> >>> print(degC_wrong)
>
> 69559.375
>
> >>> degC_correct = (mV - 500)/10
>
> >>> print(degC_correct)
>
> 19.609375